# cannot find symbol R.drawable.splash in PhoneGap Android

Tags: cordova

I know this is really very noobish question to ask but here it goes. 
I am trying to add splash to my phonegap app, and I am unable to build it. Here is build output. (note: I am using netbeans, with its phonegap support)

```
error: cannot find symbol
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
  symbol:   variable splash
  location: class drawable
  1 error
  /home/ujjwal/CODE/codesvn/html5/nbproject/build.xml:330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /home/ujjwal/Install/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:712: The following error occurred while executing this line:
  /home/ujjwal/Install/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:726: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I don't see any particular reasons for this to fail, as I am relying on netbeans to set up all the class paths and other details. 
What could possibly be wrong? Do I have to include some lib that I am missing.

Here is my config.xml's line on splashScreen

```
<gap:plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
```

can someone please point me to right direction. Thanks in advance

Edit:
Lines from my App.java

```
public class App extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
    }
}
```

Config.xml

```
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="480" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" width="800"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="800" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" width="480"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="200" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" width="320"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="320" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" width="200"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="320" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" width="480"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="480" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" width="320"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="720" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" width="1280"/>
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" height="1280" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" width="720"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole issues was because android looks for splash.png inside the res/drawable/ directory if we include the **R.drawable.splash**
The problem with netbeans is it creates a res folder in public_html which is actually not the res folder which is under platform/android/res
If we make splash.png and put it there it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to `super.setIntegerProperty` before `super.loadUrl`. Change the sequence to :

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash)
super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);
```

Comment: What is your splash screen image named.. ?

Comment: It's in the config.xml, I will edit the question with config.xml.

Comment: Did you add the files to the `res/drawable` directory.. ?

Comment: No, but is it required, I am mapping the splash screen in config.xml. Shouldn't that do the trick?

Comment: Ill get back to you on this. Can you show the entire app.java.. ?

Comment: Try removing the mapping from the `config.xml` and put the files in the relevant directories of your project. That's the standard way I guess.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. But that shouldn't cause build failure. Should it?

Comment: @pers3us : Kindly note that the correction I suggested is actually important. The `loadUrl` should be below the `setIntegerProperty`.

Comment: That I have done already, I tested it and it still gives me build problem. I will update it.